# Showing that the cube and the octahedron have the same symmetry group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am aware that the octahedron and the cube have the same symmetry group but I was wondering how we show this concretely. I have looked/been thinking about for an answer to this and I have got that as they are the dual of each other then they have the same symmetry group. However whilst I can intuitively understand why this is true  I can't find/write a proof of the following statement which the argument seems to rely on:

Every polyhedra has the same symmetry group as its dual

Thanks very much for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about: put the octahedron in a cube in the natural way (each vertex of the octahedron is at the center of one of the cube's faces). Now prove that any symmetry of the octahedron corresponds to a symmetry of the cube, and vice-versa.

Comment: Can this approach be done in general for any convex hull of finitely many points?

Comment: yes well this is basically what I was asking (just a special case of every polyhedra has the same symmetry group as it dual) but I am not sure how to start doing this

Comment: At least for the case of a cube it is immediate: after the transformation, each of the octaheadron's vertices defines the center of a face. From this, the cube is easily determined. The inverse is equally simple.